# Infer return type from function object parameter

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I can infer return type from generic parameter like this. It's working well when I use positional parameters.

```
const handleAndReturnNumber = (n: number) => n
const handleAndReturnString = (n: number) => String(n)
const doSomething1 = <R extends (n: number) => ReturnType<R>>(handle: R) => handle(2)


doSomething1(handleAndReturnNumber) // return type of function is number
doSomething1(handleAndReturnString) // return type of function is string
```

However when I use "named parameters", i.e function accepts only one parameter and its type is object I have no idea how could I achieve the same results as in code above. Is it possible to do it in TS?

```
const doSomething2 = ({handle}: {handle: Function /* ? how to infer return type here? */ }) => handle(2)
doSomething1({handle: handleAndReturnNumber}) // return type of function should be number
doSomething1({handle: handleAndReturnString}) // return type of function should be string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it the same as your example?

```
const doSomething2 = <
  R extends { handle: (n: number) => ReturnType<R['handle']> }
>({
  handle,
}: R) => handle(2);
```

Comment: Not really because R needs to extend object/interface not a function.

Comment: Is that the one you need?